# Make big groups from a lot of small groups (probably some graph problem)

Tags: python, algorithm, math, memory-management, graph-theory

I have a lot of files with groupped IDs.

File-1

| id | group_id | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | 100 | 201 |
| 3 | 200 | 210 |
| 4 | 200 | 211 |
| 5 | 300 | 200 |
| 6 | 300 | 221 |

File-2

| id | group_id | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 221 |
| 2 | 100 | 231 |
| 4 | 200 | 240 |
| 5 | 200 | 241 |

Rules:

1. Unique_id means the same across different files (so file-1.unique_id 221 is the same file-2.unique_id).
2. I also treat unique_id in one group_id as "one" (so at file-1.unique_id 201 means the same as file-1 unique id 200, because they have the same group_id; but file-2.group_id 200 is not the same as file-1.group_id 200).

What I would like to do is to create big groups, across all files.

What I do now:

1. I make graph:

File-1 semiresult

```
201->200
211->210
221->200
```

File-2 semiresult

```
231->221
241->240
```

2. And then find each record in each file to connect files groups, and end up with:

Result

| file_id | group_id | big_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 200 | 2 |
| 1 | 300 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | 3 |

My problem is - the memory. So it's easy to perform this task on two small files, but I do not know what structure/solution should I use to maybe perform it files that contains 100 000 000 records, also I want to make big_group for even 200 files.

I perform on 10/20 RPi's and I have network drive available, but I do not know how to synchronize the process.

I think that it might be some problem that has official name and maybe some implementations.

Comment: What I probably have to use is union-find algorithm. But it might not be effective on bilion of record.

Comment: Please explain how the numbers in the "big-group" column of the result table are calculated.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.05430 offers a distributive and scalable union-find that works on billions of records.  I haven't looked at it in detail though.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried a union-find algorithm, to see to what size it scales to, and whether it is sufficient?  If not, I think that would be a good first step, and would help  you ask a better question.

Comment: @btilly It's just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.